# Canon Flash Slave: 550 or 430 ex ii

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash

I have a Canon 580 exii, now i am looking for a cheap slave either canon 430 mark ii or canon 550. not sure what should i pick?

Comment: Budget?  Usage?  Depending on how important "cheap" is, would you consider a third-party strobe?

Comment: Is this not a product recommendation question as well?

Comment: Between 430 ex II and 550 yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 580 EX II supp and the 430 EX II  both support ETTL II. The 550EX only supports ETTL. Since you already have an ETTL II device, you'd be handcuffing it by going down to ETTL I. I have both a 580 EXII and a 430EXII and I love it. Shooting ETTL can be great when you don't have time to play with manual flash settings, and ETTL II improves upon that. I love that combo. The 580 EXII can control the 430EXII and all of its features. To me, combined with what Caleb said, it is an easy decision for the money and compatibility.

Also, you can set up ratios automatically... 1:2, 1:4, etc, from the camera. You can also control each flash manually from the camera. That is huge if you mount them inside softboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the 550EX was introduced in 1998 while the 430EX II was introduced in 2008, the 430EX II seems the safer bet if you're working with a modern DSLR. Speedlites do wear out over time; parts like the flash tube and capacitors are bound to fail eventually, and the zoom mechanism is also subject to wear and tear.

Comment: The 550 probably isn't going to support a lot of the more modern features that the 430 will as well, particularly when used as a slave.